# Passing parameter array list on http native get method typescript

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, ionic-framework

I am trying to pass array list parameter . parameter `codeList` contains array like

```
[
  {
    "projCode": "11-1115",
    "cblTagNo": "571_GE001-RC1"
  },
  {
    "projCode": "11-1115",
    "cblTagNo": "571_GE001-S"
  }
]
```

But I am facing the error `"invalid params object, needs to be an object with strings"`. May I know how to pass the obj array.
Here is my http call method.

```
checkCableTagList(codeList: String[]){
  this.http.setDataSerializer('json');
  console.log(JSON.stringify(codeList));
  return this.http.get('http://hostname/cable/v2/cableschedule/key/', codeList, {});
}
```

I have tried this way, It didn't work as well.

```
return this.http.get('http://hostname/cable/v2/cableschedule/key/', JSON.stringify(codeList), {});
```

Comment: do you use httpClient or just http in typescript?

Comment: Your `codeList` is an Array of Objects, not an Array of Strings. This produces the error you see when adding the array to the `checkCableTagList` function

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can make use of `HttpParams` to send this array.

```
   let httpParams: HttpParams = new HttpParams();
   codeList.forEach(code => httpParams = httpParams.append('Projects', code ));

 //Http request-
 return this.http.get('http://hostname/cable/v2/cableschedule/key/', {
   params: HttpParams 
 }).subscribe(
   (response) => //some manipulation with response 
 );
```

Comment: I have changed the post method instead of using get method. It works now.